# Application that search inside google and reply accurately

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts, artificial-intelligence, chat

I am developing a chat application in java where a user chat with the software like a bot machine. My question is, if a user writes any query or any input message it must search in google then retrieve it parse it etc.. that all i can go with. but the problem is how can i fetch the data from google based on user input. and also user should not feel that it is a simple search its a chat.

Answer (score 2):

There might be easier and simpler ways out there - but this is what I would do :

I would suggest first work on querying Google through a simple application, and work out that part effectively. Here are a few link for that:

[How to query google through desktop java app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866921/how-to-query-google-through-desktop-java-app)

[How can I Programmatically perform a search without using an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141136/how-can-i-programmatically-perform-a-search-without-using-an-api)

[Is there a way to programmatically access Google's search engine results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445308/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-access-googles-search-engine-results)

[How can you search Google Programmatically Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727662/how-can-you-search-google-programmatically-java-api)

Once you are done with this part, for implementing your chatting bot, I would suggest you to go for [AIML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIML). I personally have developed a chatting bot using AIML, and it is pretty good and accurate.

So to line up your task - first learn how to query Google through a Java program, then fetch results from it and try to dynamically create AIML files. Once done with it, use an AIML interpreter to interpret those AIML files and boom! - your bot is ready!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Google Custom Search API?

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Worth noting the cost:

> Free quota
>
> Usage is free for all users, up to 100 queries per day.
>
> Paid Usage
>
> Any usage beyond the free usage quota will fail if you are not signed
>   up for billing. Once you have enabled billing, you will continue to
>   receive 100 free queries per day. However, you will be billed for all
>   additional requests at the rate of $5 per 1000 queries, for up to
>   10,000 queries per day. If you need additional quota, please request
>   additional quota from the console.

Correct as of June 2012